# Tunnel Splitting with Openvpn Acess Server

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, firewall, openvpn

I want to be able to use my vpn for all nonbrowsing applications that require the internet (eg steam, sc2, etc) and use my normal internet for browsing (chrome, etc). How can this be done? Can it be done with my current setup?

My current setup: openvpn access server 1.8.3 on Ubuntu 11.10. The clients are all Windows 7. I have proxycap if that is useful at all. I have to have the openvpn on port 443 because of a very restrictive firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a Windows client. It can be done using policy routing on a Linux OpenVPN client (which could be the router for the Windows machines).